# Print preview special characters for registration and trademark are not superscripted

Tags: browser, printing, special-characters, print-preview

Print preview of special characters for registration and trademark are not superscripted

How do I get them to show superscripted in print preview (and the actual printed page)?

qa.crfhealth.com

Answer (score 0):

The page http://qa.crfhealth.com does not contain the registered sign ® or the trade mark sign ™ (which are presumably the characters you are referring to) in the print version, as they only appear in the navigation menu, which is omitted by the print style sheet rules.

The page http://qa.crfhealth.com/?q=solutions-services/ecoa-modalities for example contains the registered sign even in the print version. On screen, the character is practically illegible; in print preview, it is a large circled R sitting almost on the baseline. This is caused by the print style sheet http://qa.crfhealth.com/sites/all/themes/crf/css/print.css?m5kd7z and the difference is due to the stylistic difference between Myriad (the embedded font used on screen) and Arial (the font used in print version).

If you need to use the registered sign and the trade mark sign due to requirements by the marketing or legal department (the only people who care about such characters), ask them what how they want them to appear, showing some set of alternative glyphs. Then use CSS to set the font of these characters separately. This means silly-looking markup like `<span class=R>&reg;</span>` or, more honestly, `<font class=R>>&reg;</font>`, with CSS code like `.R { font-family: Calibri, Lucida Sans Unicode }` (if a superscript-like appearance is desired), for all media.